# pouchdb - get all data from database

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I need to get all the documents from PouchDB database . Can anyone tell me how to get the 'doc' from the callback function? I would like to return it as response object and also to get it in console output.

```
var db = new pouchdb('meetups');
db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: true
}).then(function (err,res) {
    console.log("Result..."+res);
    res.json({'users':res});
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want is the following:

```
var db = new pouchdb("meetups");
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
  res.json({"users": result.rows});
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

If there is an error it will be handled by your `catch` callback, so you only have one parameter (`result`) in your `then` callback. The `result` variable will include some metadata about the results (e.g. `total_rows`) as well as a `rows` property which will be an array of all of the documents in your database.

Comment: Thanks..I got it working by using " db.get(response.rows[i].id, function (err,doc){JSON.stringify(doc.title)....."

Comment: @RajeshKJeyapaul That works, but will result in an extra (and unnecessary) query against the database. In my example the `result.rows` property should contain all of the data you need. For example, `result.rows[i].doc`. If you want to iterate through the rows: `result.rows.map(function(row) { console.log(row.doc); });`